# Changing the size of UITableView programmatically

Tags: ios, ios5

I am trying to display data from a mysql database on my server. I am loading the data into a table. The problem is, I don't want this data to be the only thing on the view. I want the table to be shared with other content. Ideally, I would like the table to be able to grow and expand with how many cells their are. So if there are 3 cells, I would like it to grow to fit all 3. If there are 10, I would like it to grow to fit all 10.

It looks like Apple does this a lot. A major place I notice it is in their contacts, the phone numbers table grows and shrinks depending on how many numbers there are.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

with bellow code your tableview size decide with its content...

```
tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.contentSize.height);
```

Comment: Just a quick question, when would be the best time to call this?

Comment: when your data or also table reload and also in viewWillAppear: or viewDidAppear:

Answer (score 0):

When you say "grow", I'm not sure if you mean just the number of cells or the actual dimensions of the view itself.

If it's the cell count, use `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` in the table view's data source.  If you also want the view size to change, calculate a new rectangle for it to occupy and assign that as its `frame` property.

Comment: I mean the table view itself. I don't want the cells to scroll inside the view. I want the table view itself to grow. Do you have an example of how to make the view grow or shrink? How exactly do you figure out the height of the table view cell especially if the cell is set up to grow if there are multiple lines of text?

Comment: Hi Keith, have you succeeded in getting the solution.I have the same requirement that as cell grows, tableview height should get adjusted accordingly without scroll.Thanks in advance.